# Compare array items with HTML dataset with pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dataset

Using Jquery you can do:

```
array[0].data('id') == array[1].data('id')
```

and compare 2 items in an same array by their HTML dataset (in this case it's data-id="1"). Is there a way to do it with pure Javascript???

This is HTML. It's a list of images.

```
<li class="card" data-id="1"><img src="images/labrys.svg" alt=""></li>
<li class="card" data-id="2"><img  src="images/laurel.svg" alt=""></li>
```

....and so on
This is JS:

```
    let cardArray = []; //Empty Array for selected cards

cards.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    if (e.target.nodeName==="LI"){ // If a list element is hit...

        const data = e.target.dataset.id; //checking
        console.log(data);

        cardArray.push(e.target); //Place current card into array...
        var hit = cardArray[0].dataset.id;
        var hot = cardArray[1].dataset.id;// throws error
        console.log (hit);
        console.log (hot);
}
```

I am trying to do this:

```
var match = cardArray[0].dataset.id=== cardArray[1].dataset.id;
```

This project is a memory game:
https://github.com/StamatisDeli/memory-game.github.io

Comment: seems like cardArray has only one element??!

Comment: Please create a working snippet demonstrating the issue you are facing.

Comment: From your code, you are only pushing one card into the `cardArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **check how many items** are in the array before accessing their index.

I believe that you are trying to avoid duplicating items when the user selects a particular card multiple times through click events. if that is what you are trying to achieve, You will be facing two scenerio.

first is to make sure that the listener function does not misbehave on multiple clicks.

second is to implement a binary search algorithm to help locate items easily rather than iterating through the items one after the other during searching. the id is a great stuff to use in sorting the list items.

```
var processing = false, //used to handle radical click event triggers
cardArray = [];

//note, it is better to add your event listener, to the card container `ul`
//since click events on the li items will will bubble up to it.

cardContainer.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (processing) {
       return;
    }
    if (e.target.tagName.tolowerCase() !== 'li') {
       return;
    }
    processing = true;
    var cardlocation = searchCard(e.target.dataset.id);
    if (cardlocation > -1) {
        //card is already in array. do what you wish here
    }
    else {
        //this is a new selection. do whatever you wish here
        cardArray.push(e.target);

    }
    processing = false; //done processing.
});
```

**Implement a search algorithm**

```
/**
*This one will be slow if there loads of cards in the array
*@returns int returns the card index or -1 if not found
*/
var searchCard = function(id) {
    var len = cardArray.length;
    while (--len >= 0) {
        if (id == cardArray[len].dataset.id) {
            return len;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Binary Search**

```
/**
*used when sorting the cards
*/
var sortCard = function(card1, card2) {
    var id1 = parseInt(card1.dataset.id),
    id2 = parseInt(card2.dataset.id);
    return id1 - id2;
};

/**
* used for checking the cards search
*/
var checkCard = function(id, card) {
    return parseInt(id) - parseInt(card.dataset.id);
};

/**
*performs binary search
*/
var searchCard = function(id) {
    if (cardArray.length === 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    var low = 0,
    high = cardArray.length - 1,
    middle = parseInt((high + low + 1)/2, 10),
    locationindex = -1,
    searchindex = 0;

    cardArray.sort(sortCard); //sort the card array

    do {
        searchindex = checkCard(id, cardArray[middle]);
        if (searchindex === 0) {
            locationindex = middle;
        }
        else {
            //split and recalculate the middle
            if (searchindex < 0) {
                high = middle - 1;
            }
            else {
                low = middle + 1;
            }
            middle = parseInt((high + low + 1) / 2, 10);
       }
   }
   while (low <= high && locationindex === -1);
   return locationindex;
}
```

Comment: you are welcome. why not give the answer an upvote or mark this as the correct answer if it is